# App Store Connect Operation Error: Please upload content before committing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload the app to the app store via Xcode Version 13.3.1 (13E500a)

But getting the error as below:

```
 Please upload content before committing. With error code ENTITY_ERROR
 for id 6be3c91a-195a-4ab8-a2b4-6******
```

[image]

Comment: I think your AppStoreConnect is not yet configured properly. Thats why you are getting this error.

Comment: So annoying, also facing this issue and I'm pretty sure my iTunes connect is configured properly as I uploaded many previous version of my app without any problems until I encountered this problem.

Comment: Update: I tried 3 times in a row. The third time it uploaded without problems. So I guess the workaround is to just retry uploading it!

Comment: @MarvinKrüger For me next day It's uploaded.

Comment: Built the app again by cleaning the build folder and it worked.